# Regex to find multiple different date formats

Tags: python, regex, date

I am trying to find a regex to check if a date can be found within an string. The dates can be available in four different formats:

- 01 Decemeber 2018
- 1 December 2018
- December 2018
- 2018

I´m struggling finding the right regex. Thanks in advance!

```
date= re.search('\d{2}\W\w+\W\d{4}', elems[i].text)

if date is not None:
     elem[date'] = date.group(0)
```

Comment: Can you show your current efforts, regex that you've written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your regex to this, which has optional groups to match your optional data,

```
(?:(?:\d{1,2}\W)?\w+\W)?\d{4}
```

To support date as one or two digits, you need to change quantifiers from `{2}` to `1,2` and as in one of your samples, date part is missing hence you need to make `(?:\d{1,2}\W)` part as option by putting `?` after the group and since one of your sample doesn't have date and month part, hence you need to make `(?:(?:\d{1,2}\W)?\w+\W)` part also optional by putting `?` after the group, which will then just match your year part with `\d{4}`

On a separate note, I'll suggest you to make your regex a bit more specific if you're going to use it to match/extract text from a generic text. But in case you're going to use it to match text, which doesn't contain generic strings, then it should be okay. Do as per your needs.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r8CTfX/1)**